# Kubernetes Ingress Connection Timeout Issue: Unable to Access Microservices via DNS

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, kubernetes-ingress, minikube

I'm trying to develop a microservice app with k8s, this is my first approach to microservices application. My configuration of the deployment.yaml have the goal of creating 3 Deployments with relative services:

- db : a postgres db. Expose port 5432
- MainApi: a node api that expose port 3000. It make request to the postgres db.
- fastApi: A python api used for AI process and dataset cleaning. Expose port 8000

this is my deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: db
spec:
  selector:
    app: db
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5432
      targetPort: 5432
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: db
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: db
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: db
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: db
          image: myName/db
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              value: root
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              value: postgres
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "128Mi"
              cpu: "0.5"
            limits:
              memory: "1024Mi"
              cpu: "1"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mainapi
spec:
  selector:
    app: mainapi
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mainapi
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mainapi
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mainapi
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mainapi
          image: myName/mainapi
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "128Mi"
              cpu: "0.5"
            limits:
              memory: "1024Mi"
              cpu: "2"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: fastapi
spec:
  selector:
    app: fastapi
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8000
      targetPort: 8000
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: fastapi
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: fastapi
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: fastapi
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: fastapi
          image: myName/fastapi
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "512Mi"
              cpu: "0.5"
            limits:
              memory: "2048Mi"
              cpu: "2"
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: progettoviaggio
  labels:
    name: progettoviaggio
spec:
  rules:
    - host: progettoviaggio.test
      http:
        paths:
          - path: "/"
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: mainapi
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

my goal is to have a dns "progettoviaggio.test" to connect in the front-end application. After some research i've found that this is possible with the use of an "Ingress", after following some tutorials i've setup the ingress and once copied the ip address found doing
`kubectl get ingress`
i've mapped "progettoviaggio.test" to the address in `/etc/hosts` file.
then i check that all pods,services and ingress works correctly doing
`kubectl get pods`

```
db-678448cf9c-v46bx        1/1     Running   1 (2d ago)    3d3h
fastapi-d59547d78-bx7zf    1/1     Running   1 (2d ago)    3d3h
fastapi-d59547d78-vr8lh    1/1     Running   1 (2d ago)    3d3h
mainapi-7c75577989-mdzpf   1/1     Running   10 (2d ago)   3d3h
```

`kubectl get services`

```
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
db           ClusterIP   10.105.116.51    <none>        5432/TCP   3d7h
fastapi      ClusterIP   10.110.190.84    <none>        8000/TCP   3d7h
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP    3d7h
mainapi      ClusterIP   10.101.218.237   <none>        3000/TCP   3d7h
```

`kubectl get ingress`

```
NAME              CLASS   HOSTS                  ADDRESS        PORTS   AGE
progettoviaggio   nginx   progettoviaggio.test   192.168.49.2   80      2d1h
```

After all that i tried to connect to "progettoviaggio.test but the response was:

`ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

- i've tried to expose services individually and it works fine.
- Restart docker
- changed the services type to `LoadBalancer` and `NodePort` but the result remain unchanged
- i've verify that all pods are reachable within the cluster more than once and everything works fine

My system configuration:
MacBookPro 18,1
CPU: M1 Pro 10 CORE
GPU: M1 Pro 16 CORE
RAM: 32GB
Kubernetes:
Client Version: v1.29.1
Kustomize Version: v5.0.4-0.20230601165947-6ce0bf390ce3
Server Version: v1.26.3
minikube version: v1.30.1
docker version: 24.0.7 darwin/arm64

** update based on the requests of the comments
`kubectl get svc -A`

```
NAMESPACE              NAME                                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
default                db                                   ClusterIP   10.105.116.51    <none>        5432/TCP                     4d5h
default                fastapi                              ClusterIP   10.110.190.84    <none>        8000/TCP                     4d5h
default                kubernetes                           ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                      4d5h
default                mainapi                              ClusterIP   10.101.218.237   <none>        3000/TCP                     4d5h
ingress-nginx          ingress-nginx-controller             NodePort    10.96.145.16     <none>        80:30959/TCP,443:31788/TCP   3d
ingress-nginx          ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP   10.104.140.143   <none>        443/TCP                      3d
kube-system            kube-dns                             ClusterIP   10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP       4d5h
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper            ClusterIP   10.99.56.183     <none>        8000/TCP                     4d2h
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard                 ClusterIP   10.96.209.32     <none>        443/TCP                      4d2h
```

thanks everybody for helping

Comment: Do you have [ingress controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/) installed?

Comment: thanks for reply @zori, i hadn't done it. After installing the problem still remain

Comment: Try look at https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#example-of-loadbalancer I don't work much with minicube, but as I see there is no access at all, so `minikube tunnel` should help

Comment: from what i can see tunnel option is for LoadBalancer only, if i change all my services making them as a LoadBalancer i can connect to them but i need to use ingress type. Thanks to your reply i had found some info and ideas. i've tried to minikube ssh and when i curl my dns address seems to work perfectly but that seems to work with minikube ssh only. Apparently the problem i'm having it's a known problem of running minikube on OS different from linux. In the hope that someone have solved this problem i'll wait for more ideas

Comment: Ingress controller should be LoadBalancer type and nothing else, rest of the services should be available thought it, ingress controller works on port 80 and 443 by default, can you add output from `kubectl get svc -A` ?

Comment: when i've installed the ingress controller following the guide at: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#quick-start
i can't change the type of ingress controller.  I've added the output you asked for in question description

Comment: Ah ok, for minicube ingress controller is working as node port, so just follow https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#example-of-nodeport I guess `minikube service ingress-nginx-controller -n ingress-nginx --url` it should expose your ingress

Comment: running that command gives me this addres
http://127.0.0.1:56431
but when i try to connect, it respond with a 404 error. Futhermore this is not the configuration that i've asked for in deployment.yaml, since i ask for a dns address i expect to use THAT address to point during connection